# unity c# issue unable to get perfect position of a enemy in unity c# script using transform.position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

when I command or set an enemy to go left and then at reaching a particular state or position i say my enemy to go right but it is not going right and not reaching to perfect position here is the code I think there is no issue in the code but it is not working properly so here are some images of the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enem : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(-3f, 0f, 0f)* 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        if (transform.position.x > -29)
        {
            transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(3f, 0f, 0f) * 1 * Time.deltaTime;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please post the code itself with code format, not images. ctrl  k to the selected text for code format or betwen `` `for inlined code format `

Comment: you are doing `* Time.DeltaTime` which is the time since the last frame, which is a small amount of time that is changing from frame to frame. That seems the reason for what is being called "lack of exactitude". Remove that, and you will obtain the offset of `+ new Vector3(3f, 0f, 0f)` you are after

Comment: bro thats not working

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please post the code itself with code format, not images. ctrl k to the selected text for code format or betwen `` `for inlined format`. Thank you

Comment: [**Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: bro i have already uploaded pic click on enter image description

Comment: upload the code, not images. please read the comments

Comment: ok I got it i will upload code

Answer (score 0):

Before adding any `bool` logic, try first simply moving your element:

using UnityEngine;

```
public class SimeMoveMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(3f, 0f, 0f); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I smiled a little the moment I understood what you were trying to do.

I wrote the code imagining the result you were trying to make!

Create a cube, attach this code as component, and run the game.

```
// Gift for you friend
public class MoveTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int _direction = 1;

    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.zero;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        int direction = ShouldWeSwitchDirection(position.x, 0f);
        if (direction != 0)
        {
            _direction = direction;
        }

        transform.position += _direction * new Vector3(3f, 0f, 0f) * 3f * Time.deltaTime;
    }


    private int ShouldWeSwitchDirection(float value, float center = 0f)
    {
        float direction = Mathf.Sign(value - center);
        float distance = Mathf.Abs(value - center);

        // If X Position is larger than 29
        if (Mathf.Abs(distance) > 29)
        {
            // If X is on right side
            if (direction >= 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            // If X is on left side.
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```